# How to create a method that displays an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am trying to write a class that constructs an array that holds specific string values, and i also want to create a method in that same class that displays the array values. here is what i have so far

```
    import java.util.Arrays; 

public class Courses
{
    private int next;
    String [] studentArray;
    String classList;


    public Courses ()
    {
        String[] studentArray = new String[11];
        studentArray[0] = "CSCI 0066";
        studentArray[1] = "CHEM 003B";
        studentArray[2] = "HUM 0002";
        studentArray[3] ="MATH 0032"; 
        studentArray[4] = "CHEM 003Y";
        studentArray[5] = "MATH 0031";
        studentArray[6] = "CSCI 0026";
        studentArray[7] = "PHYS 0105L"; 
        studentArray[8] = "PHYS 0105";
        studentArray[9] = "CSCI 0013";
        studentArray[10] = "ENGL 001C";
        next = 0;
    }

    public String displayCourses()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++)
        {
            classList = studentArray[i];
        }
      return classList;
    }

}
```

Comment: `return Arrays.toString(studentArray);`

Comment: this compiles but when i do this i recieve a nullpointerEception when using that method

Comment: @NickEspino that's because you create a new array in the constructor. Do `studentArray = new String[11];` instead. See my or Elliott's answer, if you have problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Courses` constructor actually creates a local shadow of `studentArray`, so you should remove the `String[]`. Also, you might declare your array inline. I would also suggest you override `toString()` instead of creating your own method `display` that returns a `String`. Assuming you're using Java 8+, you might use `Collectors.joining`. Something like,

```
public class Courses {
    private int next;
    String[] studentArray;
    String classList;

    public Courses() {
        studentArray = new String[] { "CSCI 0066", "CHEM 003B", 
                "HUM 0002", "MATH 0032", "CHEM 003Y", "MATH 0031",
                "CSCI 0026", "PHYS 0105L", "PHYS 0105", "CSCI 0013", "ENGL 001C" };
        next = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Arrays.stream(studentArray).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, if i wanted to compare the string values in each index to a user input string, would this still work?

Answer (score 3):

Try printing instead of overwriting and returning:

```
  public void displayCourses(){
    for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++){
        System.out.println(studentArray[i]);
    }
 }
```

As mentioned by @GhostCat, printing directly is bad practice, so Create a string and append all data into in and then return as following:

```
String s = "";
public String displayCourses(){
    for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++){
        s += studentArray[i] + "\n";
    }
    return s;
 }
```

This can also be done using `StringBuffer`(Synchronous) or `StringBuilder`(Asynchronous).

As mentioned by @Shashwat, this will be more efficient using `StringBuilder`, as following:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
public String displayCourses(){
    for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++){
        sb.append(studentArray[i]+"\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
 }
```

And using `StringBuffer`:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
public String displayCourses(){
    for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++){
        sb.append(studentArray[i]+"\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
 }
```

As suggested by @MadProgrammer this can also be done using `StringJoiner`:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("\n");
public String displayCourses(){
   for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++){
       sj.add(studentArray[i]);
   }  
   retunr sj.toString();
}
```

And yes! to get rid of `NullPointerException`, Don't create a new array in constructor. just initialize it.

```
String[] studentArray;
Course(){
    studentArray = new String[11];
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Bad advice. Direct printing is fixed here. Better to actually return a string. I think you are really missing the point of the question.

Comment: @Kaushal28 using `StringBuilder` would be more efficient, instead of using a `String`.

Comment: You might also consider `StringJoiner`

Comment: @Kaushal28 so many ways and this code still produces a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Shashwat see now!

Answer (score 0):

In your display method you can use Java stringbuilder to add all your values and return as string

Answer (score 0):

The simple way: use += to concat that result string:

```
classList +=
```

Within that for loop. But of course, the more efficient approach would be to use a StringBuilder instead.

Or to use the built-in method in the Arrays class that turns arrays into String for you.

And for the record:

- the method name printClasses()  implies that this method prints the array content. In that case: just print each line.
- alternatively rename the method to getClassesAsString() for example to express what the method is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use [String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

```
public String displayCourses()
{
    return String.join("\n", Arrays.asList(studentArray)); //could use Arrays.toString too
}
```

However, in the constructor, you create another array, called `studentArray`, which overshadows, the original one, causing the `NullPointerException` So, do

```
public Courses ()
{
   studentArray = new String[11];
   //..rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ONE {

    private int next;
    String[] studentArray;
    String classList = null;
    String d = null;

    public void Courses() {
        String[] studentArray = new String[11];
        studentArray[0] = "CSCI 0066";
        studentArray[1] = "CHEM 003B";
        studentArray[2] = "HUM 0002";
        studentArray[3] = "MATH 0032";
        studentArray[4] = "CHEM 003Y";
        studentArray[5] = "MATH 0031";
        studentArray[6] = "CSCI 0026";
        studentArray[7] = "PHYS 0105L";
        studentArray[8] = "PHYS 0105";
        studentArray[9] = "CSCI 0013";
        studentArray[10] = "ENGL 001C";
        for (int i = 0; i < studentArray.length; i++) {
            classList = studentArray[i];
            System.out.println("---->" + classList);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ONE o = new ONE();
        o.Courses();
    }
}
```